# Writing Makefile in C

Tags: c, makefile

I am writing(at first time) a makefile for my program in C. This is my make file:

```
CC = gcc
FILES = in_one.c in_two.c in_two.h
OUT_EXE = out_executable
build: $(FILES)
    $(CC) -o $(OUT_EXE) $(FILES)
clean:
    rm -f *.o core
rebuild: clean build
```

Actually, everything works properly : Gcc compiler doesn't show any errors, but maybe someone could explain what does these lines mean:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o core
rebuild: clean build
```

Comment: do you understand what `build: $(FILES)` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rm (removing) or deleting all (*) the existing .o Files. So the next time you compile or call the make file you are just left with the new ones.

Build: $(Files) is creating the .o so the compiler can link them together into an executable

Comment: Removes all the core (core dump) files as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `clean` lines say that if you want to make `clean` it does not depend on anything (nothing behind ":"). Furthermore the `rm` command deletes all object files.

The `rebuild: clean build` says that if you want to make `rebuild` it depends on `clean` and `build`. So the first thing to do is `clean` (= delete all object files) and then make `build` (= compile all source files). After that there is nothing more to do so make stops.

For a quick start, make recipes have the following syntax:

```
target: dependency1 dependency2 ... dependencyN
    command1
    command2
    ...
    command3
```

So if `target` needs to be made at first all dependencies (`dependency1` - `dependencyN`) are made. After this is done `command1` - `commandN` are executed in that order.